# Validating entire form with "required" in parsley without adding "required" to individual fields

Tags: validation, parsley.js

Is there a way to validate the entire form in parsley? As in, I want to make sure that all the fields are validated as "required" without adding this keyword to each of the fields. Something like the following:

```
<form action="file.jsp" method="post" data-parsley-validate required>
```

Comment: That should totaly work. Is it not the case?

Comment: When I use this, it automatically seems to add "novalidate" in the form. Any ideas on why this could be happening? (For example: the above becomes `<form action="file.jsp" method="post" data-parsley-validate required novalidate>`

Comment: novalidate is added to prevent default html5 validation. But it won't prevent Parsley from validating fields that should inherit from parent form required directive